# bash syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator with token "@mail.com"

Tags: bash

I have a script that performs a SQL SELECT and sends some e-mails using the output but there is an issue with the script causing the error message:

> line 34: johne@mail.com: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator
>   (error token is "@mail.com")

Line 34 is:

```
if (( ${msgData[$email]:-0} < $(LC_TIME=C date -d yesterday +%s) )); then
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
${BASH_VERSION+shopt -s extglob lastpipe} 2>/dev/null

# Full path to a file to store our date offset data. Will be overwritten.
datefile=date.log

# Assign your vars or insert whatever code does so here.
user=user pass=pass db=db

function doit {
    typeset x
    for x; do
        if [[ -z $x ]]; then
            echo 'doit: missing an argument.' >&2
            return 1
        fi
    done

    typeset template=$(</dev/fd/4)
    exec 4<&-
    sqlplus "${1}/${2}@${3}" <&3 | {
        if [[ -f $datefile ]]; then
            . "$datefile" || return 1
        else
            # An associative array that maps from num -> timestamp
            typeset -A msgData
        fi

        # If we've successfully read the file containing timestamps, then overwrite with new data on RETURN
        ${msgData+trap 'trap RETURN; typeset -p msgData >"$datefile"' RETURN}

        while IFS=, read -r num email limit orders; do
            ${email:+:} continue
            if (( ${msgData[$email]:-0} < $(LC_TIME=C date -d yesterday +%s) )); then
                printf -- "$template" "email" "$num" "$limit" "$orders" |
                    /usr/sbin/sendmail -f sender@example.com -oi -t

                msgData[$email]=$(LC_TIME=C date +%s)
            else
                printf 'Mail already sent to %s within the last 24 hours... skipping.\n' "$email" >&2
            fi
        done
    }
} 5<&0 <<\SQL 3<&0 <<\TEMPLATE 4<&0 <&5-
set pagesize 0
set feedback 0

SELECT kred_lim.kunr ||','|| kust_adr.ku_email ||','|| kred_lim.kred_limit ||','|| kred_lim.kred_zu_zahlen
FROM kred_lim, kust_adr
WHERE kred_lim.kred_zu_zahlen > kred_lim.kred_limit
AND kred_lim.kunr = kust_adr.ku_nr;
SQL
Subject: Credit limit
To: %s

Customer number: %s
Credit limit: %s
Current orders: %s
TEMPLATE

if ! doit "$user" "$pass" "$db"; then
    echo 'we failed :(' >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: What line is the 34th? Can you highlight it somehow?

Comment: probably ${msgData[$email]:-0} contains a nonumeric string

Comment: make a test harness in a separate file that just sets the miniumum number of variables and the line in question, and add `set -vx` to see what is happening (as best you can) inside the command-substituions, etc. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are trying to perform a string comparison inside an arithmetic expression. Either switch to a compound expression:

```
if [[ ${msgData[$email]:-0} < $(LC_TIME=C date -d yesterday +%s) ]]; then
```

or check that you are accessing the correct element of `msgData`.

Comment: Changing that line to that has made no difference and the error message is still the same.

Comment: Hm. Is it possible that you are reaching that line without `msgData` having been declared as an associative array? I.e, `datefile` exists and is sourced, but exits with status 0 so that you don't return.

Comment: I'm not sure, at the moment `datefile` doesn't exist at all as I can't run the script at the moment due to the error message so I guess not?

Answer (score 2):

It first seemed to me that this is a limitation of the implementation of associative arrays in bash (as of v4.3.11 here).

The [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) says:

> Associative arrays are created using
>
> ```
> declare -A name.
> ```
>
> Arrays are assigned to using compound assignments of the form
>
> ```
> name=(value1 value2 … )
> ```
>
> where each value is of the form `[subscript]=`*string*.

And then you look up `subscript` a few lines earlier:

> The subscript is treated as an arithmetic expression that must evaluate to a number.

So it's saying a string "foo@bar" can't evaluate to a number, and can't be used as an array key? But that doesn't explain why strings without "@" can.

The confusing part is also that when you do the assignment manually, e.g.

```
declare -A emails_to_accounts=( \
    ["foo@bar.com"]="baz" \
    ["qux@bar.com"]="quux" \
)

for email in "${!emails_to_accounts[@]}"; do
    name=${emails_to_accounts[${email}]}
    : [...whatever...]
done
```

That works fine. Bother.

The solution for this, as it turns out, is to repeat the `declare -A` part in the assignment, like this:

```
declare -A "hash_name+=([$email]=$whatever)"
```

In the specific example above, it's probable that `${msgData[$email]:-0}` gets evaluated in integer context because you use the `<` comparison.

So I'd wager that you want to do something like quote it to escape that context first.

Or simply do it with fewer shorthands, without the `:-` modifier, which really contributes to the impression of line noise when combined with all the other punctuation on that line. For example:

```
msgTime=${msgData[$email]}
test -n "$msgTime" || msgTime=0
if [ $msgTime -lt $(LC_TIME=C date -d yesterday +%s) ]; then
```