# Impossible bash: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "")

Tags: bash, shell, operators, syntax-error, character

I know there have been a lot of similar questions here but this is pretty special, please read on.

I have a bash script that does nothing but comparing two numbers, basically like that:

```
[[ 1408039118 -lt 1401215749 ]]
```

Now, running that script throws the following error:

```
/usr/bin/pacaur: line 179: 1408039118: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "")
```

So I understand something must be wrong, this is my line 179:

```
[[ "${depsAlastmodified[$i]}" -lt 1401215749 ]] && note "f" $"no AUR metadata for ${colorR}${depsAname[$i]}${reset} package"
```

Running this through `bash -x` shows:

```
+ [[ 1408039118 -lt 1401215749 ]]
/usr/bin/pacaur: line 179: 1406628774: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "")
```

There is really nothing visible wrong with that. I tried some further debugging using `od -c` on that variable:

```
echo ${depsAlastmodified[$i]} | od -c
```

The output is:

```
+ echo '1408039118'
+ od -c
0000000   1   4   0   8   0   3   9   1   1   8 033   [   m 033   [   K
0000020  \n
0000021
```

But now I'm not sure how to read this. I understand the newline character is belonging to the echo command. But what is `033   [   m 033   [   K` exactly? And does this belong to my issue?

I also tried running that number through `bc`:

```
echo ${depsAlastmodified[$i]} | bc | od -c
```

This is the output:

```
+ echo '1408039118'
+ bc
+ od -c
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: K
0000000
```

Something is wrong with that variable. What else could I try? How to fix this?

Just for reference, this is the [full issue history](https://github.com/Spyhawk/pacaur/issues/260).

Comment: It doesn't address your issue directly but in bash, you can (should?) use `(( depsAlastmodified[i] < 1401215749 ))` for your comparison.

Comment: This one tells me the oposite http://stackoverflow.com/a/17526818/1260906

Comment: The trailing characters look like ANSI escape codes for resetting the color and erasing part of the line, respectively. How does your array get set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has something to do with [grep adding color](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/45190/19062) escape stuff at the end of line,

It's really no easy task to track this down and fix this.
For reference, if anyone else comes across this issue:
I had `GREP_OPTIONS="--color=always"` in my `~\.bashrc` file, to fix this, you need to do the following:

- Uninstall pacaur, remove the complete /tmp/pacaurtmp-*/ directory.
- Put `GREP_OPTIONS="--color=never"` (or `auto`) into your `~/.bashrc` and `source ~/.bashrc` it.
- Reinstall pacaur and do a whole system upgrade `pacaur -Syu`

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you have trailing characters in your array.

Try this with `tr -cd '[[:digit:]]'` which will delete all non digits from input:

```
echo "${depsAlastmodified[$i]}" | tr -cd '[[:digit:]]' | od -c
```

It should give:

```
0000000   1   4   0   8   0   3   9   1   1   8
0000012
```